# ColdFusion 2016 upgrade giving stored procedure error

Tags: sql-server-2008, coldfusion-2016, cfstoredproc

We are in the process of upgrading to ColdFusion 2016 to work with SqlServer 2017. Our current version (ColdFusion 10/SqlServer 2008) is working fine.

We are testing our code in a development environment to find any issues with it and I keep coming across the same error that is a little cryptic. I'm not sure if it's the combination of ColdFusion 2016 and SqlServer2008 or just an upgrade from CF10 to CF2016. It involves CFStoredProc commands.

The code is:

```
<CFSTOREDPROC DATASOURCE="MedScribeSQL" PROCEDURE="dbo.usp_ChartRestrictionCheck">
    <CFPROCPARAM CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" DBVARNAME="Org" TYPE="In" VALUE="#Cookie.Org#">
    <CFPROCPARAM CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" DBVARNAME="Chartnum" TYPE="In" VALUE="#TRIM(Variables.PTChartnum)#">
    <CFPROCPARAM CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" DBVARNAME="Username" TYPE="In" VALUE="#Cookie.Username#">
    <CFPROCPARAM CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" DBVARNAME="ReturnChart" TYPE="Out" VARIABLE="RestrictionReturnChart">
    <CFPROCPARAM CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_DATE" DBVARNAME="ReturnExpiryDate" TYPE="Out" VARIABLE="RestrictionReturnExpiryDate">
</CFSTOREDPROC>
```

When the page runs I am getting the following error:

```
Error Executing Database Query. 
[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near '='.   

The error occurred in D:/Websites/AcumenEHR/health/CustomTags/checkMRAccess.cfm: line 78
Called from D:/Websites/AcumenEHR/health/HCNHeader.cfm: line 127
Called from D:/Websites/AcumenEHR/health/HCNHeader.cfm: line 1
Called from D:/Websites/AcumenEHR/health/records/Visit_summary/hpsummary2.cfm: line 23
Called from D:/Websites/AcumenEHR/health/CustomTags/checkMRAccess.cfm: line 78
Called from D:/Websites/AcumenEHR/health/HCNHeader.cfm: line 127
Called from D:/Websites/AcumenEHR/health/HCNHeader.cfm: line 1
Called from D:/Websites/AcumenEHR/health/records/Visit_summary/hpsummary2.cfm: line 23

76 : <CFPROCPARAM CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" DBVARNAME="Username" TYPE="In" VALUE="#Cookie.Username#">
77 : <CFPROCPARAM CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" DBVARNAME="ReturnChart" TYPE="Out" VARIABLE="RestrictionReturnChart">
78 : <CFPROCPARAM CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_DATE" DBVARNAME="ReturnExpiryDate" TYPE="Out" VARIABLE="RestrictionReturnExpiryDate">
79 : </CFSTOREDPROC>
80 :
```

I can't find any information in the documentation about why this would be throwing an error. I'm wondering if anyone has had a similar experience with this and can point me in the direction of a fix since this same error occurs in a number of places.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were some changes made in CF11 on how the DBVARNAME attributes are handled. In CF10 they were essentially ignored, and since CF11 update 3 that has been 'fixed'.

You will need to make sure the values in the DBVARNAME attributes match the names of the parameters in the stored procedures **exactly**, in this case with SQL Server that likely means that you will need to prefix them with an `@`.

Here's a blog post outlining this change:
https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2015/07/coldfusion-11-and-dbvarname-attribute/

Comment: This worked. I tried a few different things and determined that this was the case and it works. Also need to test to see if adding the "@" for the parameter names will work in CF10.